# Include standalone files in subdirectories which read other files

Tags: standalone, filesystem-access

I want to use package `standalone` together with `PGFPlots` and `TikZ` to generate figures.
In particular, I want figures to be generated only if missing, using `buildmissing` package option for `standalone` when building the main document, but at the same time I want to generate them separately if I am working on them.
However, I cannot seem to make it work if the figures are in a subdirectory.

```
./
├── figures/
│   ├── sub.csv
│   └── sub.tex
├── main.tex
├── same.csv
└── same.tex
```

The main document is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildmissing]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Same directory:
\includestandalone{same}

Sub directory:
\includestandalone{figures/sub}
\end{document}
```

The standalone figure in the same directory is `same.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y] {same.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The standalone figure in the same directory reads CSV data from `same.csv`:

```
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,0
```

The standalone figure in the subdirectory is `figures/sub.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y] {sub.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The standalone figure in the subdirectory reads CSV data from `figures/sub.csv`:

```
x,y
1,-2
3,-4
5,-6
7,-8
9,-0
```

If I compile manually the figures everything works fine and PDF files are generated.
If I then compile the main document, those PDF files are included.

However, if I compile the main document before manually compiling the figures, only the first one is generate correctly.
The second one generates an empty plot, because it cannot access file `sub.csv`.
From what I understand, relative paths are always considered relative to the initial document, but in this case the initial document is in two different directories, depending if I compile the main document or the standalone figure.

I used `PGFPlots` as example, but this issue also arise if I want to include any other file with `\input{}` or `\include{}`.
For instance, I sometimes have a common preamble containing acronyms and fonts I want to use in both main document and figures, and I cannot include it from both files and have it working.

Comment: Hi Claudio, I'm the author of `standalone`. The problem here is indeed that the paths are different and the original files are not found. At the moment the bundle does not provide a solution for this out-of-the-box. If I find out how to handle this internal I might add a feature for this in future versions. You could work around this issue, e.g. by writing a suitable Makefile (gnu make) for your project which handles the generation of your subfiles.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. I ended up writing a tiny wrapper script that `cd`s in the figure's directory and builds it, and configure standalone with `\standaloneconfig{mode = buildmissing, build = {latex = lualatex, command = {./buildfigure.sh \latex \space \file}}}`. This way I can Ctrl+B from my editor to build the standalone figure, or build the main document together with all figures.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Hello Martin, has this issue been resolved recently?

Answer (score 1):

I used the [`currfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/currfile) package to solve this problem.
You can use `\currfiledir` in your `sub.tex` to construct an absolute path.

`figures/sub.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y] {\currfiledir sub.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Make sure to also import `currfile` in your `main.tex`.